# How can I find the shortest path in a directed weighted graph with a minimum cost requirement?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

I'm trying to find an efficient way to find the shortest walk (edges & vertices can be repeated) in a directed and weighted graph with a minimal requirement, ie. the shortest path with a cost of ***at least*** X (X being a number).

For example, using this graph:

[image: Example of directed weighted graph]

Let's say I want the shortest path from 0 to 2 with a minimal cost of 12.
The solution here would be 0 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2, which gives a cost of 13.

There is no cycle in this example, but there can be cycles in my case.

I've already tried using an algorithm that starts from the end (here 2), and gradually makes its way to the beginning (here 0), but it has some issues, especially when such a path doesn't exist.

Comment: google Dijkstra

Comment: @ravenspoint Yeah that's the first thing I wanted to use, but what about the minimal cost requirement?

Comment: Read the definition of the Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: @ravenspoint Ohh hold on, this is a misunderstanding because of how I formulated it, by "minimal cost requirement", I meant I need the shortest path with a cost of AT LEAST X (X being any number)

I'm going to edit the question a bit

Comment: I would say "reward" instead of "cost" and "lower bound" instead of "minimum"

Answer (score 0):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Related_problems_and_algorithms

> To obtain a ranked list of less-than-optimal solutions, the optimal
> solution is first calculated. A single edge appearing in the optimal
> solution is removed from the graph, and the optimum solution to this
> new graph is calculated. Each edge of the original solution is
> suppressed in turn and a new shortest-path calculated. The secondary
> solutions are then ranked and presented after the first optimal
> solution

In your case, select the minimum path greater or equal to X.

In detail:

```
- Find cheapest path (by Dijkstra )
- IF path cost > X THEN STOP
- Sort edges in path into ascending cost
- LOOP BEGIN
- Remove cheapest path edge not marked fixed
- Find cheapest path (by Dijkstra )
- IF path cost > X THEN 
   - IF run time more important than guaranteed optimal THEN STOP
- IF path cost did NOT increase from previous loop
   - REPLACE edge, mark fixed
- LOOP END
- SELECT cheapest > X
```

Comment: I don't think that works with cycles though, does it?
Let's say I have a graph 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 with all weights being 1, and I want a path from 1 to 4 with a cost of at least 6.
The solution would be 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 but I don't think the variation of Dijkstra you sent would work.

Comment: The solution you suggest "1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1" is ridiculous.  What practical problem would be solved by traversing the same path twice?  The solution I propose would give the result no path exists with a cost greater than X which makes much more sense.

Comment: I'm not gonna go into all the details, but I can 100% guarantee you that in my case, that solution is not ridiculous at all and the expected path would be that one, therefore my issue, I would have straight used Dijkstra if it wasn't

Comment: You need to explain in your question - otherwise your question is incorrect.

Comment: It's clearly not incorrect, I'm literally asking for a path with a condition on the cost being a minimum for it...

Comment: @ravenspoint This doesn't necessarily work. E.g. if there are two walks of cost < X that don't share an edge then no edge removal from the initial solution will result in a solution with a cost >= X even if such exists.

Comment: @Dave  Thanks for pointing out the corner case.  Dijsktra gives the cost from the source to every other node.  To handle this case you will add a check for multiple equally optimal paths that do not share any edges ( very rare! ) and remove edges from each one.  Or, simpler, run the algorithm and if the path length does not increase after removing an edge, then remove an edge from the new path - keep doing this until path length does increase.

Comment: Added check for the @Dave case to algorithm

Comment: Okay so this solution partially works. In fact in reality I'm looking for a walk, instead of a path, as @Dave pointed out by editing the question, sorry if that wasn't clear :D

Comment: @ravenspoint I'm not sure this is such a corner case. E.g., imagine a large digraph with a single very expensive arc from S to T that exceeds X, and every other arc in the graph is much much cheaper so that there are many arc-independent walks with total costs below X (which aren't necessarily equal). This is an extreme example, but you can imagine many arc-independent walks with a cost below X.